# Trouble with -match comparator

Tags: powershell

First of all, this is my first ever post on stackoverflow. If I do something wrong, please tell me.

Ok so, I'm kind of a "junior" sysadmin and I started learning powershell a few months ago.

I'm writing a script to disconnect a specific account from all the servers in my domain and to do that I execute want to execute this block of commands through multiple PSSessions :

```
if ((Get-Process -IncludeUserName).UserName -match 'myusername') {
    
    $SessionIds = ((Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where username -Match "myusername") | select SessionId -Unique)

    foreach($SessionId in $SessionIds) {
        logoff $SessionId
    }
}
```

If my logic is good, the if statement will be true if there is at least one process active under myusername. But my problem is, when I run this specific line `(Get-Process -IncludeUserName).UserName -match 'myusername')` it does not return true or false, it's just listing as many time my user name as there is a process under it.

BUT, if I specify a process name (there must be only one process running under that name) like for exemple "explorer" so :
`(Get-Process explorer -IncludeUserName).UserName -match 'myusername')`
I have the "true" response.

I could do it like that I know... But it's bothering me. And more than that! My user could be logged even if there isn't an explorer process running in his session.

Anyway, I hope I'm making myself clear. English is not my native language (like many of us here).

Thanks in advance for your participations! Have a good day.

Comment: Welcome! -match is used to match partial values. In your case -eq would work better since you are working with a known quanity. Unless your query is returning more than the actual username. In that case you'll want to include a wild character "**" in the myusername parameter and use double quotes for the expansion, i.e. "*myusername*"

Comment: Ok so, writing down all of this, I figured another way to write my if statement.
`if ($null -ne (Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where username -Match "myusername"))` and it resolved my main issue. But I would love if one of you guys would explains to me the behavior of my first attempt. What am I missing?

Comment: Hey @RetiredGeek, thanks for the answer but I think -match work great. I tried with -eq and it does not return anything... The thing is, with -match, it return "true" as long as there is only one process running under my username account. That's the thing that is bothering me.

Comment: -eq is mostly for evaluating numbers rather than strings which is why that happened. You can also use `-like`. Have you tried `(Get-Process * -IncludeUserName).UserName`. I would probably be getting the username with a different method personally.

Comment: @shadow2020 Thanks for your contribution! I figured out my main issue thanks to Bender the greatest's answer bellow. But I'm curious to read about your different approach about retrieving the username. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explaining the [`-Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#-match) behavior

First, `-Match` **on a string** works by matching on a pattern (.NET regular exression), and returning `$true` or `$false`. Specifying just a string with no other expression tokens will match any occurrence of `myusername`, so would also match on `myusername2` and `supermyusername`. In this case it's better to use `-eq`, or specify a proper expression with `-Match` if you want to match on a known format of username instead.

However, when using `-Match` **on a collection**, the behavior is a bit different. You noted that
`-Match` on a single `UserName` returns `$true` but when there are more than one it returns many instances of that `UserName`. This is because using `-Match` on a collection actually returns the objects which match that pattern in the collection. If you were to change the `-Match 'myusername'` to `-Match 'username` you would see you'd still get lots of `myusername` returned.

---

#### Addressing the main issue

To solve the "there might be more than one process for a user" problem, pipe the array of `UserName` to [`Select-Object -First 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1#example-7--rename-files-and-select-several-to-review) to select the first element of the array. You will want to select the first item returned by [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1) as `Get-Process` will return all processes, and your [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1) clause may match on multiple processes with the same `UserName`:

```bsh
if ((Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Select-Object -First 1).UserName -match 'myusername') {
  ....
}
```

Now you are no longer reliant on hoping that a process (`explorer.exe`) only has one instance of it for your script to work. Now that we understand how that works, **there is a better way to achieve what you want here**.

---

#### Make it better (Hey Jude)

We can leverage a more advanced technique called **variable squeezing** to get the list of matching processes and make sure it actually returned something in one shot:

```bsh
if ( ( $proc = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where-Object UserName -eq 'myusername' ) ){
  $sessionIds = $proc.SessionId | Select-Object -Unique

  foreach( $id in $sessionIds ) {
    logoff $id
  }
}
```

Let me explain what this code does that your original version did not do:

- `($proc = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where-Object UserName -eq 'myusername')`

  - Placing a variable assignment between `()` is called [**variable squeezing**](https://ridicurious.com/2019/03/07/powershell-variable-squeezing/), and is a way to assign a value to a variable while also outputting it to the pipeline. Note note how `$proc` is still usable after being assigned in the `if` clause.
  - Your `if` clause will evaluate as `$false` if no processes are returned and assigned to `$proc`. [This blog post explains PowerShell's truthiness well](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/boolean-values-and-operators/).
- `$sessionIds = $proc.SessionId | Select-Object -Unique`

  - [`Select-Object -Unique`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1#example-4--select-unique-characters-from-an-array) will return a uniqified collection of whatever you passed in. In other words, this will remove duplicate `SessionIds` in this case.
  - Your original strategy to get `explorer.exe` thinking there would be only one instance of it is flawed. [If you configure Explorer to launch in separate processes from the main one](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/125919-enable-disable-launch-folder-windows-separate-process-windows.html), `explorer.exe` absolutely could match on more than one instance. Even if you don't think someone would set that, all it takes is one power user to break your script.

Comment: Well, first of all, that's what I call an answer! Thanks!

So, to respond to you in order :

It's true that the match operator can be risky and thanks for the explenation of its behavior with collections!

Your solution to my main issue is good! But I'll stick with the one I found myself except for the -match operator which gives me `if ($null -ne (Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where username -like "*myusername")`

Finally, I really appreciate this explanation about the variable squeezing. I don't think it's usefull for me in this scenario but I will use it in futur scenarios!

Comment: Yeah once I get started I can't stop sometimes :D The big thing I wanted to steer you away from though was assuming there would only be a single instance of `explorer` running. Listing processes isn't much of a resource hog, but variable squeezing in an expression like that is very useful when multiple queries can put strain on other services, say AD for instance, or working with data returned from REST APIs.

Comment: Yeah don't worry, I wasn't going to use the explorer process. I understand the benefit of variable squeezing and I will definitely use it in the futur. Here, my script is pretty simple so I don't need to. Anyway your answer was very detailed and useful ! Have a good day. :)